# How can I create an underline filter with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a filter so I can underline a specific expression but i don't really know how to change a CSS value of only an expression and not the entire tag. Or if there is a better way to achieve this, so I don't have to manually create tags for the specific parts that I want to underline.

Comment: Better: Wrap it in a span and add a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this?
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tBFvh/23/)

```
<div ng-app='App'>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <span ng-bind-html-unsafe="1000000 | wrap"></span>
  </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('App',[]);

app.filter('wrap', function () {
    return function (text) {

        var t =  '<u>'+text+'</u>';
        return t;
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) { }
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it takes the tags '<u>' as text inside the parent tag and not as tags... but thanks for trying

Comment: thats what the ng-bind-html directive is for. look at the jsfiddle if it does work, install angular-sanitize , use ng-bind-html and then and the $sce.trustAsHtml... but this should work